# Tomcat not starting up after out-of-memory crash - Error code 127

Tags: linux, tomcat, out-of-memory

My tomcat on AWS linux 2 had a out-of-memory crash.  I rebooted the instance and tried to restart tomcat.  But it goes into failed state.  Below is what I see:

```
=========================
[root@ip-172-31-28-48 webapps]# systemctl start tomcat.service
[root@ip-172-31-28-48 webapps]# systemctl status tomcat.service
● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-01-24 09:38:59 +08; 6s ago
  Process: 29923 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 29933 (code=exited, status=127)

Jan 24 09:38:59 ip-172-31-28-48.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: tomcat.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Jan 24 09:38:59 ip-172-31-28-48.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit tomcat.service entered failed state.
Jan 24 09:38:59 ip-172-31-28-48.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: tomcat.service failed.
========================
```

I read that status=127 can cover a variety of problems.  No idea where to look for clues.  Can someone help me how to go about isolating the issue?